# Maintaining the Aspect Ratio of an Image leads flexible imageview height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image, aspect-ratio

I'm getting the height & width of an image from the server , based on that i'm maintaining the aspect ratio of an image,
upto to this everything works well but problem is that since we are calculating the height based on the width, the height is flexible so some white spaces(see attached image) are coming,

My Question is how to maintain the aspect ratio of an image that looks great similar to Youtube home page...

The following is the code i'm using for maintaining the aspect ratio:

```
 if (membersList.about_image.size() > 0) {
        int orgWidth=membersList.about_image.get(0).width;
        int orgHeight=membersList.about_image.get(0).height;
        int adjustedWidth=350;

        float aspectRatio=(float)orgWidth/orgHeight;
        int adjustedHeight=Math.round(adjustedWidth/aspectRatio);

        imgNews.getLayoutParams().height=adjustedHeight;
        imgNews.getLayoutParams().width=adjustedWidth;

        Glide.with(context).load(membersList.about_image.get(0).url).skipMemoryCache(false).into(imgNews);
    }
    else {
        imgNews.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.noimage));
    }
```

**Got Output as below**:

[image]

Comment: Youtube has a common size for all its thumbnails, thats why it looks so neat. Not sure what you want here

Comment: I want those gaps to be hidden with the image without streching...@dustblue

Comment: Since you are already using glide try taking a look at [transformations](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations) instead of calculating the measures manually, Center crop should do the work in your case

Comment: Then you have to set the `layout_width` of the `linearlayout` with textviews same as the picture height.

Comment: You have a choice-  keep the aspect ratio or don't stretch.  You can't do both.  Although small amount of stretching isn't a big deal.

Comment: use adjustiewBound true : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: I want to keep the aspect ratio @GabeSechan

Comment: Then you need to accept that their will be white space. Or you need to use the same image size everywhere and fixed heights.